# When try to pass date the slashes occur division

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a variable var that contains a date "29/5/2017" in my page. Now i am trying to pass this variable to a function that is stored in a separate js file. My issue is when i debug the js i see a number 0,0028... The js believes that this is a number a makes a division. how can i prevent this and pass just the date?
the var in my aspx file is :

```
var mydates = '29/5/2017';
```

the function call in my aspx file

```
calldate(mydates);
```

the function in the js file

```
function calldate(mydates) {

alert(mydates);

 }
```

Comment: you seem to have a type error `mydates` and `mydate`

Comment: Check your variables name

Comment: this is not a variable name problem, or he wouldn't get 0.0028 (which is 29 divided by 5 divided by 2017), probably a typo in the post. I am almost sure that you do something with this variable between the moment you set it and the moment you display. Something like adding another var which is a number? an eval? conversions can be automatic in JS

Comment: double the / so you have '29//5//2017' or use replace function to replace "/" with "//"

Comment: I have edit my typo issue

Comment: Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have not provided a complete question, and your code doesn't demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use double quotations to single quotations mark during init variable

```
var mydates = "29/5/2017".toSting();
```

and user .toString() function for canvart to string.

Thanks

Comment: hi that didn't help. it is continue to make the division

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing date as string try to pass variable as Date datatype.
there might be chances that the variable getting changed before calling the function.

```
<pre>
var mydates = Date("29/5/2017");
</pre>
```